# Open google chrome via terminal with specific dimensions and positions using bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell, google-chrome, terminal

Is it possible to Open google chrome via terminal with specific dimensions and positions using bash, so far i have all the profiles opening `enter code here`

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 1"  &
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 2"  &
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 3"  &
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 4"  &
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 5"  &
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 6"  &
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 7"  &
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 8"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=XXXXXXXXXX --window-size=800,600 --window-position=0,0 --app="http://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: Is this for OSX though ?